# Cocoa Bindings with NSComboBox

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have Cocoa Bindings working with a NSComboBox that shows and autocompletes values based on a Managed Object Context. My issue is trying to get the current selection after the user either selects from the dropdown or the autocomplete text is used. I know that the Array Controller class has a selected objects property, but when I try to use it to pull out the selected object I get nothing. With a NSComboBox do I have to set the selection once the text/selection of the combo box occurs or is there something I'm missing setting up the Array Controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A combo box allows any arbitrary string to be entered, right? (You're not limited to the items you can autocomplete, unlike a popup menu.) So it doesn't have a concept of selected item, since the text in it might not correspond to any item in your database.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003002/what-are-the-correct-bindings-for-an-nscombobox-for-use-with-core-data) seems to address a similar issue, declaring it to be unsolvable using only bindings, and links to a [blog post](http://frankschmitt.org/2007/06/comboboxen) that has some hints on what code needs to be added. The gist of it is that, when the user finishes editing the combo box, you create your own fetch request in code and use the response from that to link up the model.